# How do I filter for prices using Satchmo/django?

Tags: django, e-commerce, satchmo

I'd like to find the minimum and maximum prices for a defined category of products.

I'd also like to be able to do the reverse, i.e, find all products given a defined price range.

The problem is that Satchmo does not have price in it's product model.   How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Min/max prices for a category:

```
Product.objects.filter(category=some_category).aggregate(Min('price'), Max('price'))
```

Products filtered by price range:

```
Product.objects.filter(price__price__range=(5,10))
```

Comment: Thanks! Works like a charm.  I guess I didn't realize there was a separate Price table.The only thing I would add for future readers is that the first statement should have Min('price__price'), Max('price__price') so you get the actual price instead of the id's.  Thanks again.